# What is the difference between Highlighted and Selected UIButton's State?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

Can anyone tell me What is the difference between Highlighted and Selected state of a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState):

***Highlighted state** of a control. A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up event.*

and

***Selected state** of a control. For many controls, this state has no effect on behaviour or appearance. But other subclasses may have different appearance depending on their* `selected` *state.*

this is the pure difference between the states.

Answer (score 95):

The answers from 2012 aren't incorrect, but some might find the explanation in the UIControl docs to be…anemic. I personally find this explanation from the [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW8) to be more helpful:

> There is a subtle but important distinction between a cell’s highlighted state and its selected state. The highlighted state is a transitional state that you can use to apply visible highlights to the cell while the user’s finger is still touching the device. This state is set to `YES` only while the collection view is tracking touch events over the cell. When touch events stop, the highlighted state returns to the value `NO`. By contrast, the selected state changes only after a series of touch events has ended—specifically, when those touch events indicated that the user tried to select the cell.
>
> […snip…]
>
> [image]

Although this documentation is specifically for collection view cells, the explanation holds pretty well across the Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Comment: what about focused? I can't understand that state

Comment: You may be confusing the topic of this post with something else, @Honey. There is no UIControl state called "focused". You may want to post a new question. :) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618245-state

Comment: @Honey ~I believe "focused" doesn't apply to iOS.~ Focus applies to tvOS since you're using a remote/game controller to scroll between views, aka switching "focus".  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation

The focus environment is also made available to iOS. Although the purpose of this is probably rare, I can see iPhone/iPad games supporting connection of a bluetooth controller which would need to have focus environment support.