# How to use highLightCell in UICollectionVieCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For my collection view, I am implementing pretty much all my selecting, deselecting function in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath. I came across this following function and I was wonder if there is an example of using the highlighting feature for the collectionViewCell. Most of the SO answers does not really use this "highlight" feature and they ended up pointing me back to didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath (Not sure why?)

```
func highLightCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath, highlight: Bool) {
```

Comment: What do you mean "How to use"? Do you do the difference between highlight & selection of a cell?

Comment: Yeh, I am curious what this "highlight" feature dose as I could implement most feature from didSelect and didDeselect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Highlighted and Selected UIButton's State?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628563/what-is-the-difference-between-highlighted-and-selected-uibuttons-state)