# How to make a UIButton show highlighted image upon touch in a UICollectionViewCell like outside a Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have several UIButtons within UICollectionViewCells and I am unable to make them react to show a highlighted image as they do outside a UICollectionView.

There seems to be a delay and the highlighted image is only shown if you long press down on the button. This is a problem I have experienced before and would like to get to the bottom of it.

This is the code for setting a standard button image for normal and highlighted states.

```
   // inside GeneralCollectionViewCell
   let generalButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
       button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "general_button")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "general_button_highlighted")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .highlighted)
    return button
}()

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifer", for: indexPath) as! GeneralCollectionViewCell

       cell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(generalButtonHandler(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

       return cell
   }
```

Any help on how to fix this annoying problem would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using an `@IBAction func` event handler such that when a button is pressed, an image is displayed?

Comment: Can you try setting this main thread.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31059885/3746301

Comment: "There seems to be a delay and the highlighted image is only shown if you long press down on the button." - `UICollectionView` descends form `UIScrollView`, which has a boolean property called `delaysContentTuches`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and your help. @NicolasMiari solved the issue for me. Had no idea UIScrollView had that property.

Comment: @Edward it's been around since the very beginning I think (iPhone OS 2.0?). It's purpose is to give the scroll view a hint of whether it should interpret a tap as the beginning of a scroll action right away, or wait just a little to see if it's actually directed at one if its subviews.